# Rotate nxn matrix around x-axis by an angle theta in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, rotation

I have **nxn matrix** in 2D space; I would like to rotate the matrix  around the x-axis using matlab. Where the x-axis pass through the center of the matrix (pass through the point [n/2 n/2].

I found the Matlab function `B = rot90(A)` which rotate the matrix A by 90 degree. But I’m looking for a method that rotate matrix A by any given angle (e.g. 30, 45, 170 degree) around the x-axis.

Comment: If you rotate a matrix by any given angle there would be some buffer in the resulting matrix. My guess is you are doing this for an image in which case `imrotate` would come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can as well try `imrotate()`. This function is from the Image Processing Toolbox, but since its main input is a matrix (either real or logical) it'll work also for non picture-related matrices (I've tried with a `magic` matrix).

The syntax is:

```
B=imrotate(A,theta);
```

where `A` is you matrix, `B` is the rotated version of `A` and `theta` is the rotation in degrees. The rotation is performed in counterclockwise direction around its center point; to rotate the matrix clockwise, specify a negative value for `theta`.